# Plot 2D geodata as function of longitude and latitude

Tags: cartopy

I would like to plot from the following NetCDF file (`R90C_20P_MSG_201403250100.nc`) the 2d array `RFnet` as function of the 2d arrays `LONGITUDE` and `LATITUDE`.

Download of NetCDF file:
https://gigamove.rwth-aachen.de/de/download/fa5c22f8009f2af3f2c59b5d92ceea7f
or here https://drive.google.com/file/d/17s2XtzS6P6rvT_ceJLnH_dN_9A1S8ViR/view?usp=sharing

I tried the following:

```
import xarray as xr
data = xr.open_dataset('R90C_20P_MSG_201403250100.nc', engine='netcdf4')
print(data)
```

which give as output:

```
<xarray.Dataset>
Dimensions:    (image_y: 565, image_x: 1215)
Dimensions without coordinates: image_y, image_x
Data variables: (12/15)
    LONGITUDE  (image_y, image_x) float32 ...
    LATITUDE   (image_y, image_x) float32 ...
    TAUCO      (image_y, image_x) float32 ...
    RFLW       (image_y, image_x) float32 ...
    RFSW       (image_y, image_x) float32 ...
    TAUCI      (image_y, image_x) float32 ...
    ...         ...
    OLRCICO    (image_y, image_x) float32 ...
    RSRCICO    (image_y, image_x) float32 ...
    RFnet      (image_y, image_x) float32 ...
    ATD        (image_y, image_x) float32 ...
    FUEL       (image_y, image_x) float32 ...
    PC         (image_y, image_x) float32 ...
```

I can extract e.g.:

```
LONGITUDE=data['LONGITUDE']
LATITUDE=data['LATITUDE']
RFnet=data['RFnet']
```

and access the corresponding data with

```
LONGITUDE.data
LATITUDE.data
RFnet.data
```

A simple plot would be:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

fig = plt.figure(figsize=(8, 4))

ax = fig.add_subplot(111)
img=plt.imshow(RFnet.data, cmap='seismic', vmin=-10, vmax=10)
ax.set_aspect('equal')

cbar = fig.colorbar(img, location='bottom', shrink=0.6, pad=0.15, ax=ax)
cbar.set_label('RFnet')

plt.show()
```

[image]

**How can I plot `RFnet` as function of `LONGITUDE` and `LATITUDE`?**

LATITUDE AND LONGITUDE ARE 2d ARRAYS:

[image]
[image]

Comment: I am not 100% sure what you mean (my lack of technical understanding) but did you see https://xarray.pydata.org/en/v0.7.2/plotting.html#maps ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
fig = plt.figure(figsize=(12, 12))
pc = ccrs.PlateCarree()
ax = fig.add_subplot(projection=pc, extent=(-55.530094, 55.530094, 33.582264, 66.823235))

ax.set_global()
ax.coastlines(resolution='50m', # alternative: '110m', '50m', '10m' 
              color='grey') 
ax.gridlines(draw_labels=True)

x = LONGITUDE.data
y = LATITUDE.data
c = RFnet.data
norm=mcolors.Normalize(vmin=-10, vmax=10)
cmap = "seismic"

ax.set_extent(extents=(-20, 20, 32, 52)) # x0, x1, y0, y1 in degrees

im = ax.scatter(x, y, c=c, cmap=cmap, norm=norm, s=2)

cbar = fig.colorbar(im, location='bottom', shrink=1, pad=0.05, ax=ax)
cbar.set_label('RFnet')

plt.show()
```

[image]